# Late variable expansion in gnu Makefile

Tags: gnu-make

I split a big file using the split command in a `Makefile` recipe.

```
trails : $(OBJ)
    sort -m $? | accumulate.py --threshold 30 | split -C 10MB -d -a 3 - trail.
```

I then rename the resulting files to have the `.acc` extension. The idea is to have an implicit rule applied on this extension later.

The issue I face is that variable expansion happens before the `.acc` files are generated. For example the following rule doesn't produce anything:

```
all: $(wildcard *.acc) trails
    @echo $?
```

Using the `patsubst` function doesn't work either because I don't know in advance how many output files `split` will generate.

PS. I split the files to take advantage of the ability of make to parallel the jobs: `make -j 16` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use recursive make.  Perform the split operation in this makefile, then invoke a recursive make to handle the rest.  Your question was not completely clear, but I think you want something like this:

```
all: trials
         $(MAKE) recurse

trials: $(OBJ)
         sort -m ...

recurse: $(wildcard *.acc)
         echo $?
```